# ngRepeat:dupes - over an object array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

ng-repeat showing "Duplicate Key in Repeater" over JSON object array. "track by $index" is also not working.

Angular code

```
        result = doAjaxCall('','json',"http://localhost:8181/admin/last10query");           
        $scope.querylist = result;
        console.log($scope.querylist);
```

HTML code

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in querylist">
   <td>{{x.query}}</td>
   <td>{{x.id}}</td>  
</tr>
```

the JSON array

```
[{"id":38,"query":"mm","temp_id":null,"topic_id":null},
{"id":37,"query":"n","temp_id":null,"topic_id":null},
{"id":36,"query":"nn","temp_id":null,"topic_id":null},
{"id":35,"query":"mm","temp_id":null,"topic_id":null},
{"id":34,"query":"nn","temp_id":null,"topic_id":null},
{"id":33,"query":"m","temp_id":null,"topic_id":null},
{"id":32,"query":"m","temp_id":null,"topic_id":null},
{"id":31,"query":"hi","temp_id":null,"topic_id":null},
{"id":30,"query":"j","temp_id":null,"topic_id":null},
{"id":29,"query":"h","temp_id":null,"topic_id":null}]
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you have a plunker or jsfiddle we can look at?

Comment: sorry but i can provide screenshot

Comment: Hard to see how you could synchronously return data from `doAjaxCall()`. Is `result` what you expect it to be...same array as shown in image?

Comment: yes, it is same as shown in image. in console https://i.stack.imgur.com/AiEnD.png and in http response https://i.stack.imgur.com/AiEnD.png

Answer (score 0):

```js
angular.module("a",[]).controller("ac",function($scope){
$scope.querylist =[{"id":38,"query":"mm","temp_id":null,"topic_id":null},
{"id":37,"query":"n","temp_id":null,"topic_id":null},
{"id":36,"query":"nn","temp_id":null,"topic_id":null},
{"id":35,"query":"mm","temp_id":null,"topic_id":null},
{"id":34,"query":"nn","temp_id":null,"topic_id":null},
{"id":33,"query":"m","temp_id":null,"topic_id":null},
{"id":32,"query":"m","temp_id":null,"topic_id":null},
{"id":31,"query":"hi","temp_id":null,"topic_id":null},
{"id":30,"query":"j","temp_id":null,"topic_id":null},
{"id":29,"query":"h","temp_id":null,"topic_id":null}];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="a" ng-controller="ac">
<table>
<tr ng-repeat="x in querylist track by $index">
   <td>{{x.query}}</td>
   <td>{{x.id}}</td>  
</tr> 
</table>
</div>
```

I don't know how you are getting the error. See the snippet it is working for us.

I got this kind of issues in Angular 2. So in this case you could initialize the `querylist` object globally.

please do this

```
$scope.querylist =[]
 result = doAjaxCall('','json',"http://localhost:8181/admin/last10query");           
        $scope.querylist = result;
        console.log($scope.querylist);
```

Comment: it is still not working. I have added "track by $index" to my code but it returning a blank list which is more than the number of object in the array.

Answer (score 0):

If your json objects have unique Id, Then you can try `track by id`,

ex:

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in querylist track by x.id">
   <td>{{x.query}}</td>
   <td>{{x.id}}</td>  
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue by using angular $http.get, i dont know why custom ajxa is not working.

```
    $http.get("http://localhost:8181/admin/last10query")
      .then(function(response) {
         $scope.myWelcome = response.data;
    });
```

Comment: dude! the question you posted is totally different

Comment: I didn't get your point. could you please elaborate little bit so I can understand